# Relationship Graph with D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, graphing

How would I create the following graph with D3? I don't know the name for this type of visualization, and the closest I could find were "force-directed" graphs.

Legend: Filled nodes are people, non-filled nodes are attributes (e.g. favorite color).

[image: Intended graph]

Comment: Shameless self-promotion: You might want to try my library, [JSNetworkX](http://felix-kling.de/JSNetworkX/) (a port of the NetworkX graph library). It lets you model and visualize graphs (using D3).

Comment: Looks like a force layout. If you have certain constraints on node positions (e.g. the colored nodes in the "centres"), you'll have to implement them yourself.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff any chance you have examples of how to do that, or perhaps resources I could look at to figure it out?

Comment: I'm not aware of any examples that have such complex constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hacked together a gross but working version: http://bl.ocks.org/hijonathan/5793014

Basically, I started with an array of `people` nodes that had some properties on them. I then loop through that and generate new nodes for each property, adding a `target` to it to link it back to the original node.

From there, you can use properties set on those two node types to style them and create corresponding nodes.

Answer (score 3):

This is my version: http://jsfiddle.net/doraeimo/JEcdS/embedded/result/
which is easy to show system performance and network flow.

```
code is not here
```